# How can I automatically submit the Facebook URL sharer form?

Tags: html, facebook, url, urlhelper

I am trying to figure out, how can I automatically submit a url at the following page

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php

without actually clicking on the submit button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find that from the page source. There is a form defined...

`<form action="/sharer.php" method="get">`

and the button is a submit button, which means that when you click the button, the form data is sent as a get request to http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php - in other words, it submits back to itself.

---

Update - asker wants to know how to submit the form without clicking on the link.

The form is:

```
<form action="/sharer.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" class="inputtext DOMControl_placeholder" id="share_input" name="u" placeholder="http://" value="http://" title="http://" />
  <input type="hidden" name="appid" value="2309869772" />
  <label class="mrm uiButtonNoText uiButton uiButtonConfirm uiButtonMedium" id="share_submit">
    <input value="Share" type="submit" />
  </label>
</form>
```

So you need to GET a URL with form data something like the following

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=your_encoded_url&appid=yourappid`

Comment: yes, i understand it,but how can i make this share button to submit himself without click on him.can i ?